# Connecting a disjointed edge post edge detection

Tags: opencv, edge-detection, canny-operator

I wonder if anybody could tell me if there's a method for connecting edge lines that have parts missing. E.g. I have an image with a roughly circular blob, I've applied a Canny edge detection method and it returns and three quarter crescent edge, whereas I'd like it to form a region that could be picked up by a Hough transform.

I've been playing around with this with openCV. I've tried finding contours, but no such luck.

Many thanks.

Edit: example contour output to try Hough transform on (top left):

[image]

Should add, I can detect a circle for that image, it would just be nice to be able to make it a disjoint region.

Comment: Can you post the input image?

Comment: @bikz05 it's not for a specific problem, just in general. even disjoint lines. I can edit an example in, though.

Comment: @bikz05 I've added an example of the crescent type problem in the top left.

Comment: in very general: use n times dilation followed by n times erosion. less general:
1. find out what kind of edges you expect: in your example it's a circle. 2. detect partial objects: chamfer matching or in your example circles. 3. add missing edges to detected partial object.

Comment: @MikeMiller Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586123/filling-gaps-in-shape-edges

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, I'll give it a try.