# How to fill gap in entrance and exit of a maze?

Tags: java, image, algorithm, image-processing

Image 1 (Before):
[image]
Image 2 (After):
[image]

Hi, is there an algorithm/method for closing of the entrance and exit of a maze as shown in image 1 and 2.

Comment: I've added the correct image now :D

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26597915/6436977), similar use case but you may have to adapt to your maze scenario.