# Extend part of an object

Tags: python, opencv

I'm attempting to extend the 'tail' of an arrow. So far I've been able to draw a line through the center of the arrow, but this line extends 'both' ways, rather than in just one direction. The script below shows my progress. **Ideally** I would be able to extend the tail of the arrow regardless of the orientation of the arrow image. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this. **Image examples below, L:R start, progress, goal.**

```
# import image and grayscale
image = cv2.imread("image path")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("original",image)

# inverts black and white
gray = 255 - image
cv2.imshow("Inverted", gray)

# Extend the borders for the line
extended = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray, 20, 20, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
cv2.imshow("extended borders", extended)

# contour finding
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(extended, 1, 2)
cont = contours[0]
rows,cols = extended.shape[:2]
[vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(cont, cv2.DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)
leftish = int((-x*vy/vx) + y)
rightish = int(((cols-x)*vy/vx)+y)
line = cv2.line(extended,(cols-1,rightish),(0,leftish),(255,255,255), 6)
cv2.imshow("drawn line", line)
```

[image: Start][image: progress][image: goal]

Comment: use `cv2.moments` on the contour. those values can tell you which way it points.

Comment: Maybe some of these ideas can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408652/remove-and-measure-a-line-opencv/67410527#67410527

Comment: Thanks, that's a link to my previous question :)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks Christoph. It seems like cv2.moments is the way to go. I asked about them on another post (on which you commented), but it was removed because I asked for resources/reccommendations. I'm at a loss as to how most parts of image moments work. I'm going through youtube/reading to better understand, but no progress past the basics. How can you tell which way the arrow points?

Comment: I'll try a few things and prepare an answer. it really helps to know some statistics (variance, covariance, skewness, etc) and then see the similarities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Definition

Comment: are you still interested in this problem?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for your explanation, and I am still interested in the problem. I understand moments from a stats point of view, I'm just having a problem visualizing it in terms of pixels. It's also not always clear, to me, which moment is what. I see (now) that µ20, µ02, and µ11 are part of a covariance matrix. But it's not clear to me (yet) how or why that can solve my particular problem. I will go through the example outlined below and try and understand. I see the power/potential of using these, so I really want to get it!. Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: I don't know what moment is what either, but fortunately all the publications seem to stick to the same notation, and I just look stuff up and apply it. the covariance matrix contains the "slope" of a line fit. the arctan extracts an angle from that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for sharing this perspective with me. I tend to overthink these things, and taking a set back to re-assess the literature, read your comments, and work through the program you wrote, is going a long way towards clarifying things. Much appreciated!

Comment: if and when you feel it is appropriate... https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Moments" can be strange things. They're building blocks and show up most often in statistics.

It helps to have a little background in statistics, and see the application of those calculations to image data, which can be considered a set of points. If you've ever calculated the weighted average or "centroid" of something, you'll recognize some of the sums that show up in "moments".

Higher order moments can be building blocks to higher statistical measures such as *covariance* and *skewness*.

- [Using covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment#Examples_2), you can calculate the major axis of your set of points, or your arrow in this case.
- [Using skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Relationship_of_mean_and_median), you can figure out which side of a distribution is heavier than the other... i.e. which side is the arrow's tip and which is its tail.

This should give you a very precise angle. The scale/radius however is best estimated using other ways. You'll notice that the radius estimated from the area of the arrow fluctuates a little. You could find the points belonging to the arrow that are furthest away from the center, and take that as a somewhat stable length.

Here's a longish program that implements the two ideas above and shows the direction of an arrow:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# utilities to convert between 2D vectors and complex numbers
# complex numbers are handy for rotating stuff

def to_complex(vec):
    assert vec.shape[-1] == 2
    if vec.dtype == np.float32:
        return vec.view(np.complex64)
    elif vec.dtype == np.float64:
        return vec.view(np.complex128)
    else:
        assert False, vec.dtype

def from_complex(cplx):
    if cplx.dtype == np.complex64:
        return cplx.view(np.float32)
    elif cplx.dtype == np.complex128:
        return cplx.view(np.float64)
    else:
        assert False, cplx.dtype


# utilities for drawing with fractional bits of position
# just to make a pretty picture

def iround(val):
    return int(round(val))

def ipt(vec, shift=0):
    if isinstance(vec, (int, float)):
        return iround(vec * 2**shift)

    elif isinstance(vec, (tuple, list, np.ndarray)):
        return tuple(iround(el * 2**shift) for el in vec)

    else:
        assert False, type(vec)

# utilities for affine transformation
# just to make a pretty picture

def rotate(degrees=0):
    # we want positive rotation
    # meaning move +x towards +y
    # getRotationMatrix2D does it differently
    result = np.eye(3).astype(np.float32)
    result[0:2, 0:3] = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(center=(0,0), angle=-degrees, scale=1.0)
    return result

def translate(dx=0, dy=0):
    result = np.eye(3).astype(np.float32)
    result[0:2,2] = [dx, dy]
    return result

# main logic

def calculate_direction(im):
    # using "nonzero" (default behavior) is a little noisy
    mask = (im >= 128)

    m = cv.moments(mask.astype(np.uint8), binaryImage=True)

    # easier access... see below for details
    m00 = m['m00']
    m10 = m['m10']
    m01 = m['m01']
    
    mu00 = m00
    mu20 = m['mu20']
    mu11 = m['mu11']
    mu02 = m['mu02']

    nu30 = m['nu30']
    nu03 = m['nu03']

    # that's just the centroid
    cx = m10 / m00
    cy = m01 / m00
    centroid = np.array([cx, cy]) # as a vector

    # and that's the size in pixels:
    size = m00
    # and that's an approximate "radius", if it were a circle which it isn't
    radius = (size / np.pi) ** 0.5
    # (since the "size" in pixels can fluctuate due to resampling, so will the "radius")

    # wikipedia helpfully mentions "image orientation" as an example:
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment#Examples_2
    # we'll use that for the major axis
    mup20 = mu20 / mu00
    mup02 = mu02 / mu00
    mup11 = mu11 / mu00
    theta = 0.5 * np.arctan2(2 * mup11, mup20 - mup02)

    #print(f"angle: {theta / np.pi * 180:+6.1f} degrees")

    # we only have the axis, not yet the direction

    # we will assess "skewness" now
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Definition
    # note how "positive" skewness appears in a distribution:
    # it points away from the heavy side, towards the light side

    # fortunately, cv.moments() also calculates those "standardized moments"
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_moment#Standard_normalization

    skew = np.array([nu30, nu03])
    #print("skew:", skew)

    # we'll have to *rotate* that so it *roughly* lies along the x axis
    # then assess which end is the heavy/light end
    # then use that information to maybe flip the axis,
    # so it points in the direction of the arrow

    skew_complex = to_complex(skew) # reinterpret two reals as one complex number
    rotated_skew_complex = skew_complex * np.exp(1j * -theta) # rotation
    rotated_skew = from_complex(rotated_skew_complex)

    #print("rotated skew:", rotated_skew)

    if rotated_skew[0] > 0: # pointing towards tail
        theta = (theta + np.pi) % (2*np.pi) # flip direction 180 degrees
    else: # pointing towards head
        pass

    print(f"angle: {theta / np.pi * 180:+6.1f} degrees")

    # construct a vector that points like the arrow in the picture
    direction = np.exp([1j * theta])
    direction = from_complex(direction)

    return (radius, centroid, direction)


def draw_a_picture(im, radius, centroid, direction):
    height, width = im.shape[:2]

    # take the source at half brightness
    canvas = cv.cvtColor(im // 2, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    shift = 4 # prettier drawing

    cv.circle(canvas,
        center=ipt(centroid, shift),
        radius=ipt(radius, shift),
        thickness=iround(radius * 0.1),
        color=(0,0,255),
        lineType=cv.LINE_AA,
        shift=shift)

    # (-direction) meaning point the *opposite* of the arrow's direction, i.e. towards tail
    cv.line(canvas,
        pt1=ipt(centroid + direction * radius * -3.0, shift), 
        pt2=ipt(centroid + direction * radius * +3.0, shift), 
        thickness=iround(radius * 0.05),
        color=(0,255,255),
        lineType=cv.LINE_AA,
        shift=shift)

    cv.line(canvas,
        pt1=ipt(centroid + (-direction) * radius * 3.5, shift), 
        pt2=ipt(centroid + (-direction) * radius * 4.5, shift), 
        thickness=iround(radius * 0.15),
        color=(0,255,255),
        lineType=cv.LINE_AA,
        shift=shift)

    return canvas


if __name__ == '__main__':
    imfile = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) >= 2 else "p7cmR.png"
    src = cv.imread(imfile, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    src = 255 - src # invert (white arrow on black background)

    height, width = src.shape[:2]
    diagonal = np.hypot(height, width)
    outsize = int(np.ceil(diagonal * 1.3)) # fudge factor

    cv.namedWindow("arrow", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv.resizeWindow("arrow", 5*outsize, 5*outsize)

    angle = 0 # degrees
    increment = +1
    do_spin = True
    while True:
        print(f"{angle:+.0f} degrees")

        M = translate(dx=+outsize/2, dy=+outsize/2) @ rotate(degrees=angle) @ translate(dx=-width/2, dy=-height/2)

        im = cv.warpAffine(src, M=M[:2], dsize=(outsize, outsize), flags=cv.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv.BORDER_REPLICATE)
        # resampling introduces blur... except when it's an even number like 0 degrees, 90 degrees, ...
        # so at even rotations, things will jump a little.
        # this rotation is only for demo purposes

        (radius, centroid, direction) = calculate_direction(im)

        canvas = draw_a_picture(im, radius, centroid, direction)

        cv.imshow("arrow", canvas)

        if do_spin:
            angle = (angle + increment) % 360

        print()

        key = cv.waitKeyEx(30 if do_spin else -1)
        if key == -1:
            continue
        elif key in (0x0D, 0x20): # ENTER (CR), SPACE
            do_spin = not do_spin # toggle spinning
        elif key == 27: # ESC
            break # end program
        elif key == 0x250000: # VK_LEFT
            increment = -abs(increment)
            angle += increment
        elif key == 0x270000: # VK_RIGHT
            increment = +abs(increment)
            angle += increment
        else:
            print(f"key 0x{key:02x}")
    
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: arrow, slightly rotated, information overlay]